# Converting raster into geostatistical layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation, arcgis-10.4, srtm, geostatistical-analyst

I have downloaded a raster surface (SRTM) with pixel size equals to 30*30, and I want to use that surface as a geostatistical layer for further analysis. Is there any available tool that converts directly raster surface into geostatistical layer? I am using ArcGIS 10.4.1.

Therefore, if it does not exist any available tool, this methodology sounds accurate?
1) Considering the extent of the raster surface, I will construct grid points every 30 meters. 
2) Using extract values to points tool, I will attach Z coordinates as attributes of grid points layer.
3) Interpolation of grid points using IDW tool(geostatistical analyst toolbox), gaining a new updated SRTM.

How accurate is this procedure comparing the raw SRTM with the modified SRTM that was developed through grid points?

Comment: Have you looked at this tool, http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/geostatistical-analyst-toolbox/create-geostatistical-layer.htm

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE Marios. Please refine and edit this question to include a single answerable question.

Comment: Create geostatistical layer tool consists a pre-existing geostatistical layer. In my case, I have under my possesion a raster surface and I want to convert it to a geostatistical layer. This is the first time that I am using the geostatistical analyst toolbox, so I am trying to fully understand what actually a geostatistical layer represent.